Databricks Notebook execution failure : Cluster Failure
enter image description here
I am using ADF to run  the ETL ad within the ETL i have a databricks notebook execution step. This error happened once and it was resolved from the next ETL run. any idea what might have caused this?
it resolved itself did not do anything.

Your Azure subscription is limited in the number of virtual machines that can be provisioned.
It was resolved when others completed their jobs, and it freed up the VM quota.

What's happening is your VM quota for your subscription is being exceeded when new VM's are being spun up for your ETL process.
If you have the correct permissions, you can view the Virtual Machine quotas for each region in your subscription by going to "Usage + Quotas" under Settings of your subscription. You can then request an adjustment to your sub admin to either increase or decrease the quota of virtual machines for each VM family.
